# Some confusion with preg_replace

Tags: php

I am very confused with preg_replace, I have this string and I would like to change ONLY the number before the _

```
$string = 'string/1_491107.jpg';
$newstring = preg_replace('#([0-9]+)_#', '666', $string);
```

But then I get "string/666491107.jpg" instead "string/666_491107.jpg"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here is matching the numbers in the parenthesis as `$1` in your replacement. You don't actually say "only the stuff in parenthesises should be replaced".

You could do it like this:

```
$string = 'string/1_491107.jpg';
$newstring = preg_replace('#[0-9]+_#', '666_', $string);
```

or you could use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (only match a number sequence followed by an underscore, but don't include the underscore in the match):

```
$string = 'string/1_491107.jpg';
$newstring = preg_replace('#[0-9]+(?=_)#', '666', $string);
```

[**Regex 101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gG3mK6)

Comment: +1 for a very neat solution. Clearly my regex skills are rusty.

Comment: @andrewsi In the right situations, negative/positive lookahead/behinds are amazing and definitely things that are great to know about.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the underscore as part of the text to be replaced; so you also need to include it in the replacement:

```
$string = 'string/1_491107.jpg';
$newstring = preg_replace('#([0-9]+)_#', '666_', $string);
```

Comment: Yes i did this, but is there other way (with other function maybe) to do it witout include the underscore ?

Comment: You need the underscore in the search to stop it matching other numbers - does your initial `string/` have numbers in it?

Comment: i have many strings and many differents pattern and 1 function for all, so in ideal way deal witout the underscore is better for me, "h2ooooooo" give me the way. Thanks you both.